# Azure SSISDB does Log Cleanup automatically?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have over the last few years created some Azure SQL Servers with SSISDB, Integration Services Catalogs and corresponding Integration Runtime in ADF.

From my SSISDB knowledge from on-prem experiences, i always remember to set the Operations Log Retention Period to a few weeks, and lover the number of project versions. But a friendly colleague told me "It's fine you're setting the cleanup parameters, but there is no background job for cleaning up the logs. So you have to call the cleanup stored procedures in SSISDB yourself in ADF or other automation".

I tried to google for Azure SSIS DB and log cleanup, and I found articles describing how "you can call" the SSISDB cleanup stored procedures yourself. But it's not clear if the Azure SQL Server does it automatically or not. On a on-prem SQL server, there is a SQL Agent Job for doing this every night, but the Azure SQL server does not have the SQL Agent available, so I don't think the SSISDB log cleanup is running automatically in Azure. Right now I create a Pipeline in ADF calling the two clean up stored procedures in SSISDB, just to be sure the cleanup is done correctly.

Does anyone know, if the Azure SQL Server is calling the cleanup stored procedures in the background, or do we need to start the cleanup ourselves using ADF or other Azure automation?

Answer (score 0):

In ADF we can create automatic cleanup process.

I crated sql server in azure portal and created database and created three tables and create stored procedure to delete old seven days data using below code:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE DeleteRecent AS
BEGIN
DELETE Student
WHERE  DATEADD(day,-7,GetDate()) > RDate
Delete [dbo].[product]
WHERE  DATEADD(day,-7,GetDate()) > RDate 
Delete [dbo].[employee] 
WHERE  DATEADD(day,-7,GetDate()) > RDate  
END 
GO
```

In Azure data factory I created pipeline and create copy activity
copy activity Source:

[image]

[image]

Copy activity sink:

[image]

[image]

I linked the copy activity to the stored procedure activity. In that stored procedure I added sql stored procedure .
Stored procedure:

[image]

I added delete activity to the stored procedure.

[image]

I run the pipeline I t successfully run. files are deleted to my requirements.

[image]

Output:
[image]

I added schedule trigger to the pipeline according to my requirements.